# Add Index for two multi tables

Tags: java, sql, jpa

I have two tables:

Table 1- company: has following columns:

- company_id
- company_key

Table 2- user: has following columns:

- user_id
- company_key
- name

I want to add indexing in a way such that I can use `company_key` to look for an entry in Table 2.

example : `/users?company_key="my_key"`

What approach should I be using?

I want to use indexing such that my user table is indexed with company_key, any suggestions about the approach.

Also, how can I implement this in JPA?

Thanks

Comment: Why not reference the company by its primary key?

Comment: The use case says the user has access to company_key and not its primary key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want a standard index on user.company_key. I haven't used JPA recently but it looks like you need to add the @Index annotation to company_key for @Entity user. Note that this index will probably be in addition to the unique index (primary key) on user.user_id.